# warning: LFLAGS is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Octave, use LDFLAGS instead

Tags: 19.10, octave

Ubuntu 19.10

Octave 5.1 flatpak every time I install an application I get this error then the CPU usages reaches 100%

```
pkg install control-3.2.0.tar.gz
warning: LFLAGS is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Octave, use LDFLAGS instead
```

**UPDATE**

after waiting for a long time ( 5 to 15 minutes approx ) the package has been installed